# enum-based factory with templates cannot convert types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums, factory

I have encountered a problem that is a bit too big for my head. Searching for it is another complicated problem as I don't imagine what exactly to search for. So I hope someone would point me in a proper direction.

The issue arises when implementing a factory with enum to pick variants which are template classes. The issue is that compiler performs type checking even for the impossible cases. The minimal example is below:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class Base {
 public:
  Base() {}
};

template <class T1>
class A : public Base<T1, T1> {
 public:
  A(): Base<T1, T1>() {}
};

template <class T1, class T2>
class B : public Base<T1, T2> {
 public:
  B(): Base<T1, T2>() {}
};

enum class Type {
  TYPE_A, TYPE_B
};

class Factory {
 public:
  template<class T1, class T2>
  static Base<T1, T2>* Create(Type type) {
    switch (type) {
      case Type::TYPE_A:
        return new A<T1>();
      case Type::TYPE_B:
        return new B<T1, T2>();
    }
    return nullptr;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char const * argv[]) {
  Base<int, double>* ptr = Factory::Create<int, double>(Type::TYPE_B);
  delete ptr;
  return 0;
}
```

and an error message for those you don't want to run this:

```
test_template_factory.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static Base<T1, T2>* Factory::Create(Type) [with T1 = int; T2 = double]’:
test_template_factory.cpp:38:69:   required from here
test_template_factory.cpp:29:26: error: cannot convert ‘A<int>*’ to ‘Base<int, double>*’ in return
         return new A<T1>();
                          ^
```

Is there a way around this? Is there an approach that would avoid it while keeping the flexibility? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your construct seems too complicated to me to be right. You could try `class S { public: virtual ~S() {} }; ... class Base : public S` and later: `S* ptr = Factory::Create...`, but then again, maybe you should rethink your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should choose what to do at compile-time, not at runtime.

Something like this can help you.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class Base {
 public:
  Base() {}
};

template <class T1>
class A : public Base<T1, T1> {
 public:
  A(): Base<T1, T1>() {}
};

template <class T1, class T2>
class B : public Base<T1, T2> {
 public:
  B(): Base<T1, T2>() {}
};

enum class Type {
  TYPE_A, TYPE_B
};

class Factory {
 public:
  template<Type type, class T1, class T2>
  static Base<T1, T2>* Create() {
    return create_helper<type, T1, T2>::apply();
  }
private:
  template<Type type, class T1, class T2>
  struct create_helper
  {
     static Base<T1, T2>* apply() { return nullptr; }
  };
};

template<class T1, class T2>
struct Factory::create_helper<Type::TYPE_A, T1, T2>
{
   static Base<T1, T2>* apply() { return new A<T1>(); }
};

template<class T1, class T2>
struct Factory::create_helper<Type::TYPE_B, T1, T2>
{
   static Base<T1, T2>* apply() { return new B<T1, T2>(); }
};


int main(int argc, char const * argv[]) {
  Base<int, double>* ptr = Factory::Create<Type::TYPE_B, int, double>();
  delete ptr;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ForEveR. This looks really neat and does exactly what I expected the original code to do. Thanks for a nice hint!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your design is that you can not create `A` for *arbitrary* `T1` and `T2`. Imagine your code was

```
Base<int, double>* ptr = Factory::Create<int, double>(Type::TYPE_A);
```

This is definitely an error, because none of possible  `A`'s is a subclass of `Base<int, double>`. And this is the error observed by the compiler, because when it does the instantiation of `Factory::Create<int, double>`, it does not yet know that you will pass `TYPE_B` to it.

A possible solution to this is to provide specialization for `Factory::Create<T1,T1>`, something along the lines:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class Factory {
 public:
  static Base<T1, T2>* Create(Type type);
};

template<class T1>
class Factory<T1,T1> {
 public:
  static Base<T1, T1>* Create(Type type);
};


template<class T1, class T2>
Base<T1, T2>* Factory<T1,T2>::Create(Type type)
{
    switch (type) {
      case Type::TYPE_A:
        throw "can't create A";
      case Type::TYPE_B:
        return new B<T1, T2>();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template<class T1>
Base<T1, T1>* Factory<T1,T1>::Create(Type type) 
{
    switch (type) {
      case Type::TYPE_A:
        return new A<T1>();
      case Type::TYPE_B:
        return new B<T1, T1>();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

...
  Base<int, int>* ptr1 = Factory<int, int>::Create(Type::TYPE_B);
  Base<int, int>* ptr2 = Factory<int, int>::Create(Type::TYPE_A);
  Base<int, double>* ptr3 = Factory<int, double>::Create(Type::TYPE_B);
  Base<int, double>* ptr4 = Factory<int, double>::Create(Type::TYPE_A); // throws
```

Note that I moved template parameters to the class to allow for partial specialization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Petr! Specialization is a solution I though about, but that I deliberately wanted to avoid. Also the example you provide in the beginning is exactly the point of my question. I understand why the code does not compile, but on the other hand, from a logical point of view I would assume preprocessor to be smart enough to figure it out.
`Base<int, double>* ptr = Factory::Create<int, double>(Type::TYPE_A);` - this is definitely an error and I want the compilation to fail in this case. But there is no logical error if I use `TYPE_B`.

Comment: @niosus, that's not the preprocessor, but the compiler itself. And the problem is that it compiles the function not yet knowing where it will be called from (you might have called it even from a separate compilation unit for all it knows). Therefore it can not know what you will pass to `Create()`. You may have read the type from console for example...

Comment: yep, you are correct. It indeed has no way of knowing what it will need from the enum. Thanks, I now understand the behavior much better.